# A Trie to A Patricia Trie

Tags: java, search-engine, trie, patricia-trie

I'm trying to write a simple search engine which uses [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)(a node contains just one character) data structure to find the words. And when it gets the "compress" command from user, the trie should turn into a form of [a patricia trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree).(a node contains strings that are common with their children)

i have done the concatenating the strings part, but the problem is children concatenated with their parent are still there.(They should have been deleted.) And i thought, by writing a "clear" method, I could deal with it.

Here is my solution, but it is not working:

```
public void toPatriciaTrie() {
    toPatriciaTrie(root);
    clearTheTrie(root); // the method call is here.
}

public void clearTheTrie(Node<String> v) {
    for (Node<String> w : v.getChildren()) {
                    // finds out if the parent contains the children
                    // if yes, deletes the children.
        if (v.getElement().indexOf(w.getElement()) != -1) {
            w = null;
        }
        else if (w != null) {
            clearTheTrie(w);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the main, and the output:

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Trie trie = new Trie();
    System.out.println("false " + trie.contains("stack"));
    // here the second one is the name of the file containing the word 
    // and the other one is its index in the file.
    trie.addToTrie("stack", "asd.txt", 3);
    trie.addToTrie("star", "asd.txt", 5);
    trie.addToTrie("jaws", "asdf.txt", 7);
    trie.addToTrie("java", "asdadsad.txt", 9);
    System.out.println("true " + trie.contains("stack"));
    System.out.println("true " + trie.contains("star"));
    System.out.println("true " + trie.contains("jaws"));
    System.out.println("true " + trie.contains("java"));
    trie.print();
    trie.toPatriciaTrie();
    System.out.println();
    trie.print();
}
```

Output:

```
false false
true true
true true
true true
true true
j a v a w s s t a r c k 
ja a va a ws s sta ta a r ck k
```

How can I deal with this problem? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you try to clear the children.

This part:

```
for (Node<String> w : v.getChildren()) {
                // finds out if the parent contains the children
                // if yes, deletes the children.
    if (v.getElement().indexOf(w.getElement()) != -1) {
        w = null;
    }
    ....
}
```

Does not remove the child, it sets the reference to the child in the to null, but it leaves the children in c intact. You must tell v to remove the child.